# Using add_difference() function in gtsummary to present mean difference instead of standardized mean

Tags: gtsummary

When creating a table with the add_difference function like the example below, the difference between the two drug users will be presented along with the 95% CI and a p-value. This mean difference is standardized, and for the difference between the proportions (e.g., binary variables) would be slightly different than the actual difference. Example: The actual Tumor response difference between the two drug users is -5%, but its reported standardized difference is -4.2%.

```
trial %>% 
select(-c("stage")) %>%
  tbl_summary(by = trt,
              statistic = list(
                all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)"
              )) %>%
  add_difference()
```

Is there a way to report the actual mean difference instead of the standardized mean difference for the binary variables in this example and still get 95% CI for the mean? (e.g., Tumor-response difference -5% instead of -4.2% Or Patient-died difference to be -6% instead of -5.8%)

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the binary variables in your post, so I've subset the table to include those only.

I think the issue you're reporting is just a difference in rounding. See below. Rounding for both the raw rates and the rate difference can be modified.

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.1'

trial %>% 
  select(trt, response, death) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by = trt,
    statistic = all_categorical() ~ "{p}%",
    digits = all_categorical() ~ 2,
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_difference() %>%
  as_kable()
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **Difference** | **95% CI** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tumor Response | 29.47% | 33.67% | -4.2% | -18%, 9.9% | 0.6 |
| Patient Died | 53.06% | 58.82% | -5.8% | -21%, 9.0% | 0.5 |

<sup>Created on 2023-06-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>